# How to make toggle() work in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I am doing a problem in a book on jQuery. I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="switcher" class="switcher">
  <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
  <button id="switcher-default">Default</button>
  <button id="switcher-narrow">Narrow</button>
  <button id="switcher-large">Large</button>
</div>
```

And am trying to make the buttons toggl on/off by clicking the title. Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
 $('#switcher h3').toggle(function() {
   $('#switcher button').addClass('hide');
}, function(){
   $('#switcher button').removeClass('hide');
});
```

For some reason, the H3 element (title) immediately hides itself upon page load and I am unable to select it. Really, the buttons should be hiding, not the H3, right?

Here's the css:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Must be an old book. The toggle you're using was deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: I would suggest usign an older version of jQuery with the book.

Answer (score 2):

`toggle` event method has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9, jQuery 1.9 uses `toggle` display method and hides your element.

You can use `click` and `toggle` *effect* methods instead:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#switcher h3').click(function(){
       $(this).siblings('button').toggle();
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler on your `h3`, rather than a [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) handler.

Then you can simply use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) or just plain [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) on `$('#switcher button')`.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#switcher h3').click(function() {
   $('#switcher button').toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `toggle()` immediately hides/unhides the elements.

You seem to be looking for:

```
$(function () {
   $('#switcher h3').click(function() {
     $('#switcher button').toggle();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: There is a .toggle event binding method that he is correctly using, though the method has been removed in 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly faster than the current answers:

```
$(function () {
   var switcher = $('#switcher');
   switcher.find('h3').click(function() {
     switcher.find('button').toggle();
  }); 
});
```